# Join or match value from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables . Based on the first table I need to check if it is locked or not.

In the below example , if the combination is present then I would pick else it should match with 'All' and bring that record.

**Lock Table**

[image]

**Transaction Table**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Query tried** - But it is doing a cross join . I understand the reason but could not solve it

```
SELECT a.GROUP,a.OFFICE,b.LOCK
FROM T_ITEMS a INNER JOIN LOCKED_T b
ON a.ORG=c.ORG
AND (a.OFFICE =b.OFFICE OR b.OFFICE='All')
AND a.GROUP=b.GROUP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is match on group or use all as a "wildcard". The problem is that you are matching on both for one of the items -- so you get two results.

So what you do is the first join

```
SELECT a.GROUP, a.OFFICE, b.LOCK
FROM T_ITEMS a 
LEFT JOIN LOCKED_T b ON a.ORG = c.ORG A 
                     AND a.OFFICE = b.OFFICE 
                     AND a.GROUP = b.GROUP
```

Now take those results and try to fill in the missing ones (missing ones will have a null in the lock column

```
SELECT 
    BASE.GROUP, BASE.OFFICE, COLLESCE(BASE.LOCK, L.LOCK) AS LOCK
FROM
    (SELECT 
         a.GROUP, a.OFFICE, b.LOCK
     FROM 
         T_ITEMS a 
     LEFT JOIN 
         LOCKED_T b ON a.ORG = c.ORG  
                    AND a.OFFICE = b.OFFICE 
                    AND a.GROUP = b.GROUP) BASE
LEFT JOIN 
    LOCKED_T L ON BASE.ORG = L.ORG 
               AND L.OFFICE = 'All' 
               AND base.GROUP = L.GROUP 
               AND BASE.LOCK IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I look at this as a "defaulting" problem.  That can be solved with two `left join`s:

```
SELECT i.GROUP, i.OFFICE,
       COALESCE(l.LOCK, l_default.LOCK)
FROM T_ITEMS i LEFT JOIN
     LOCKED_T l
     ON l.ORG = i.ORG AND l.OFFICE = i.OFFICE LEFT JOIN
     LOCKED_T l_default
     ON l_default.OFFICE = 'All' AND l_default.GROUP = i.GROUP AND l.ORG IS NULL;
```

As the number of combinations grows, this gets trickier.  So a more generalizable alternative uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT i.*,
       (SELECT MAX(l.LOCK) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY NULLIF(l.OFFICE, 'All) NULLS LAST,NULLIF(l.GROUP, 'All) NULLS LAST
        FROM LOCKED_T l
        WHERE (l.OFFICE = i.OFFICE OR l.OFFICE = 'All') AND
              (l.GROUP = i.GROUP OR l.GROUP = 'All')
       ) as LOCKED

FROM T_ITEMS i;
```

Oracle 12C supports lateral joins so this can actually be in the `FROM` clause instead.

Comment: isn't this the same as my answer except you put both joins in the same query?